# What are the advantages of having Angular 2 frontend on nginx?

Tags: tomcat, angular, nginx

Our project architecture contains Angular 2 on the front end and Java EE running on Tomcat (or JBoss).  So far we have the frontend running on Tomcat also.

What are the advantages of running Angular 2 on the separate nginx server, does it have sense?

Answer (score 4):

Using nginx server makes sense. An Angular app consists of static files - html, js, images, etc. When the user enters the URL of you app it has to be downloaded to the browser first, and only after it'll be making requests for dynamic data.

If you deploy your Angular app inside a WAR (or expanded) under Tomcat, each user of your app will make a request to Tomcat just to see the landing page of the app. Tomcat and other application servers would create a thread for each request, which takes memory (Servlets 3.0 helped a little in this regard). If you have thousands of users, your Tomcat instance may simply die.

By placing static resources under nginx (it doesn't have big overhead for each request), your Tomcat doesn't need to do any work until the app is downloaded to the browser and it made the first request for data.

Another advantage is that you can configure load balancing on the nginx server, so it'll be redirecting requests to one of the Tomcat instances in a cluster.